# How to delete the apps backup created by "Super Backup" app?

Tags: nexus-4

I recently used "Super Backup" to backup my apps/data before I flashed a new version of CM10.1 on my rooted Nexus 4 device. After I finished flashing the ROM and booted up with the new image, I restored most of my apps and all of my data.

My question is: There is provision to delete SMS Backups which are created by this app. There are similar provisions for Contacts Backups, Call Logs Backups, Bookmarks Backups but there is NO PROVISION from within this app to delete the Apps Backup.

Is there a better way of deleting the Apps Backups data which is on my local storage than just physically deleting the folders/file using a File Explorer app?